# Matrix chain Multiplication Different Recursive definition

Tags: algorithm, matrix, dynamic-programming, matrix-multiplication

Matrix Chain Multiplication has a dynamic programming solution where a recursive definition is used which works like this :

```
Problem : multiply i to j 
Sub-problem : multiply i to k + multiply k+1 to j + multiplication cost
```

and this looks straight forward to memoize, due the repeating `(i,j)` sub-problems. But the following recursive definition which is bit different, I am facing difficulty memoizing it :

```
Can someone help memoizing this algo for matrix chain multiplication : 

P is sequence of orders of matrices.
For eg, A(2,3)*B(3,4)*C(4,5), then P = {2,3,4,5}, i.e. order of ith matrix is P[i-1]*P[i]
also assumed P is 0-indexed.

Here I am multiplying adjacent matrices and recursing

Pseudocode :  

chain_mul(P, n) {
    if(n = 1)   return 0

    min_cost = inf
    for( i = 1 to n-1) {
        cost = P[i-1]*P[i]*P[i+1] + chain_mul(P-{P[i]}, n-1);

        if(cost < min_cost) min_cost = cost
    }
    return min_cost
}
```

Here repeating sub-problem is structure of P, like I have shown below : [image: Example of sub-problem recursion tree]

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Please show a [mre] and choose a language c or c++ not both

Comment: Interesting problem. I did a google for matrix chain multiplication and landed on a pretty good video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=prx1psByp7U. I think it does a good job explaining the process.

Comment: @JosephLarson I am using a different reursive definition, not the video one. Indeed video is a good explanation

Comment: Any feedback on my answer?

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be memoized efficiently, because the argument P, iterates over all the subsets of the initial set P, so the memory required would be O(2^n).

The algoritms that can be memoized call the function specifying sections of the matrix chain, each section is characterized by two numbers, start and end index. The number of segments will be something like `(n * (n + 1) / 2)`, and it is easy to implement a data structure to store and retrieve the results indexed by two numbers (e.g a matrix).